# Kernel of $f$ where $f(AB)=f(BA)$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $f$ be a linear functional where $f$ is not identically $0$. If $f(AB)=f(BA)$ for all $n \times n$ matrices $A$ and $B$, then $f(C)=0$ implies $C = AB-BA$ for some $A,B$.

I am not sure how to show that these are the *only* matrices in the kernel of $f$. Constructing $A$ and $B$ explicitly seems too difficult and trying to prove the contrapositive isn't getting me anywhere. Could I have a small hint?

Comment: What about $f(X)=0$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Good point. I should have excluded that.

Comment: Use the fact that it is a linear function. In particular if $f(AB)=f(BA)$ then $f(AB) - f(BA)=0$. (Rember that if f is linear then $f(0)=0$);

Comment: @AlexA I am not sure how that helps. $f$ need not be injective.

Comment: in fact it doesn't need to be injective

Comment: Do you know that what $f(AB)-f(BA)$ is equal to?(using the property of linearity)

Comment: @AlexA your comments are off the mark. The OP is trying to show the converse of what you are proposing.

Comment: @AlexA It seems that you're arguing the converse of the question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: this is not the commutator subgroup, but the subspace of commutators in the ring sense.

Comment: My suggestion for the original problem would be to play around with different combinations of $A,B$ being elementary matrices with only one entry nonzero. I suspect this will show that $f$ is a multiple of the trace.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thanks for the correction - I was thinking the Lie bracket and saying the commutator.

Comment: There is already a non-zero functional that has this property: the trace. Therefore, $\frac{n}{f(I)}f(X)=tr(X)$. Therefore, your problem is equivalent to proving that matrices of trace $0$ are equal to the commutator of two matrices.

Comment: Sorry, noticed the error!

Comment: Let me put the link there in case the answer below gets deleted. You can check a proof that a trace zero matrix is a commutator [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf). That solves your problem using my comment above that your functional is a multiple of the trace.

Comment: @MichaelBurr, yes, my comment doesn't address the fact that you would expect linear combinations of commutators in general.

Comment: @totoro: I agree that $f$ is a multiple of the trace, but your "Therefore, $\frac{n}{f(I)}f(X)=tr(X)$" requires some kind of argument. I suggested using elementary matrices to derive the result, though there may be a simpler way.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip I already said what needs to be done. Trace zero matrices are commutators. Therefore, they are both the kernel of $tr$ and in the kernel of $\frac{n}{f(I)}f$. Since $f$ is nonzero, and $\frac{n}{f(I)}f(I)=n=tr(I)$, then $\frac{n}{f(I)}f=tr$. Two linear functionals that have the same kernel and coincide at a vector outside the kernel are equal.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Moreover, it is not clear what you mean by "elementary matrices with only one entry nonzero". What people call elementary matrices, have non-zero determinant. Therefore, they should have many nonzero entries (at least one for every column).

Comment: @totoro Thanks for the clarification. I meant matrices which are nonzero in only one place. (I carelessly forgot that the term elementary matrices meant something a little different.) In any event, I agree with your argument now that I understand it. 1) Two linear functionals with the same kernel must differ by a scalar. 2) the kernel of $f$ can't be any larger than that of trace for dimension reasons. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The essential point to show is that the *set* $S$ of all commutators $AB-BA$ is a *subspace* of the space of square matrices, and that it has codimension$~1$; then any nonzero linear form that vanishes on all of $S$ necessarily vanishes *only* on$~S$. Since one can take for $f$ the trace function, the required property is certainly not vacuously true, and in can only hold if $S$ is equal to the set of traceless matrices (the kernel of the trace function). So to prove the statement is equivalent to proving that any traceless matrix is in$~S$.

This is indeed a fact, as was indicated in a [link provided in a comment by totoro](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/MathH110/trace0.pdf). It is not hard to see that commutators *span* the space of traceless matrices, but since there is no obvious way to write a linear combination of unrelated commutators as another commutator, there appears to be no shortcut to explicitly showing each traceless matrix to be a commutator; I can give no easy proof.

Comment: Thanks for this. Why does the subspace of commutators have codimension 1? I can't seem to convince myself of it

Comment: Never mind. I've shown it by finding an explicit basis